# PHP logout script not working

Tags: php

I have a logout script where I'm trying to clear all session data.  Whenever I do this i can navigated back to any page and the variables are still being used.

```
<?php
session_start();
session_destroy();
header('Location: index.php');
?>
```

Comment: Pressing back will usually show a cached version of the page. Refreshing on that cached page, which makes a new request, should show as logged out.

Comment: you are right it is cached.

Comment: Have a look at:: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31735428/prevent-browser-back-button-cache
It probably will answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

You should disable the cache on the pages that change on login

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
header("Pragma: no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
header("Expires: 0 "); // Proxies.
```

This code is from [prevent browser back button cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31735428/prevent-browser-back-button-cache/).