# Where is LoginController@Logout Laravel 5.6 (PHP)?

Tags: php, laravel

I am new in Laravel and using **Laravel 5.6**. I want to edit that where the user will be redirected after logout. So I checked the `web.php` file and then by going in **CMD** I typed `php artisan route:list` all routes came up, there is a `POST` method of `logout` and its controller is `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@logout` so I checked the `LoginController` there is nothing except following code, where is the `logout` method???

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
}
```

I have also searched, what I found is to change the $redirectTo variable's value but it's not woking because it's the URL after login.

Comment: Code is in `AuthenticatesUsers`. But you can overwrite the default login behavior.

Comment: can i define that in `LoginController` as a new method `logout` and redirect it where I want???

Comment: Yes. You can. You can use any controller to overwrite. Just take care of the routes.

Comment: @SougataBose I have solved this I have one more question, it takes 90 mint to post 1 more so can u help a little bit???

Comment: How can I help you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logout function is inside

```
use AuthenticatesUsers;
```

It looks like so

```
/**
 * Log the user out of the application.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function logout(Request $request)
{
    $this->guard()->logout();

    $request->session()->invalidate();

    return redirect('/');
}
```

The redirectTo is used by the AuthenticatesUsers; trait

```
use RedirectsUsers
```

Which looks like

```
public function redirectPath()
{
    if (method_exists($this, 'redirectTo')) {
        return $this->redirectTo();
    }

    return property_exists($this, 'redirectTo') ? $this->redirectTo : '/home';
}
```

The routes for auth comes from the

```
Auth::routes();
```

in web.php

Comment: I have solved this I have one more question, it takes 90 mint to post 1 more so can u help a little bit???

Comment: sure, what is the problem?

Comment: I am getting an error that when the user is *logged out* it must not show the Homepage which is Authenticated, but after logging out **when I press the back button** *it shows the home page*, but after refresh it shows Login form, I want that if anyone presses the back button it must not show the homepage, and if I **logout again** from the homepage which *came up by pressing back button* it shows **"The page has expired due to inactivity. Please refresh and try again."**

Comment: The problem is that the browser usually does not reload the page when using the back button, because it caches it. Why is it a problem though, the logged out user wont be able to get any new information from the system in the home view

Comment: Well sure if it really is a problem you might be able to solve it with some javascript that checks if the user i logged in and forces the page to reload. Or read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31735428/prevent-browser-back-button-cache

Comment: No problem (y).